# C++ Cannot list files of dir C:\Users\User\Recent\

Tags: c++, windows, file, filesystems

I'm trying to create an application that will delete specific files from `C:\Users\User\Recent`. For this I want to go through all the files first and see if the file should be deleted.

I've tried many things, for example:

```
const char* path2 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Recent\\";
for (const auto& dirEntry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path2))
{
     std::cout << dirEntry << std::endl;
     std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
}
```

This just doesn't print anything,

and when i try to open the dir with opendir from the dirent.h library it just returns NULL

```
const char* path2 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Recent\\";
DIR *dr;
dr = opendir(path2);
// dr = NULL
```

Everything else i tried gave me similar results.

Comment: See if `perror` prints out a useful error message after failure. If it doesn't, fall all of the way back to Windows API calls, `FindFirstFile`, should be enough, and see what sort of error diagnostics you get. I don't know my Windows-isms all that well, but it's probably going to be a permissions problem if the user you're running the program under isn't "user".

Comment: I tried to print a good error but there was none. Then I tried again to work with Windows API calls but just like before I didn't get any results. I also noticed that the "Files" in the Recent folder are just links to the actual files. Could the files not be recognized because of this?

and no it's not a permissions problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `SHGetFolderPath` to get the correct location of the Recent folder. It is usually somewhere inside %AppData%.

If you wish to "clean" this folder correctly, accessing it directly from the file system is not ideal because there is mirrored information stored in the registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs`).

To properly deal with this you should call `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` on the file you want to delete and on the shell item, bind with `BHID_SFUIObject` to get `IContextMenu` and invoke the delete verb. Or better yet, use `SHGetKnownFolderItem` and never look at the file system...

Comment: Thank you so much! `SHGetKnownFolderItem` worked very well!